# HP Envy 15-j101ex - Windows 10 Pro x64 - HyperV - startup Freeze

Tags: windows-10, bios, bluetooth, hyper-v, hp-envy

I have an HP Envy 15-j101ex laptop.  It is running Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.  It has the latest BIOS from HP: Insyde F.65

I need to turn ON Hyper-V (hyper-V Hypervisor) to create some virtual machines.  So I have added the Windows Features (turned on in Control Panel Add Windows Features): Hyper-V Platform and Hyper-V Management Tools.

For the Hyper-V Hypervisor to work, Hardware Assisted Virtualization needs to be turned ON in the BIOS.  The laptop does support Hardware Assisted Virtualization.  But when "Virtualization Technology" is enabled in the BIOS (with UEFI enabled),  this ends in a boot freeze with the rotating circle (under the HP logo) and the laptop never starts up.  Virtualization Technology has to be turned OFF or the laptop will not boot up.

I have checked the Microsoft site and ran the tools suggested: coreinfo.exe, SLAT status check, DEP checked.  Everything on the laptop is as expected in the requirements for Hyper-V.

Any suggested fixes?

Note: I have seen suggestions to disable Bluetooth and uninstall the driver.  But if I uninstall Bluetooth drivers, Windows automatically reinstalls the Bluetooth drivers after a restart.  And if the BT device is just disabled in device manager (without drivers uninstall), the problem (failed boot) still occurs.

Comment: Is it possible to disable Bluetooth in the BIOS?

Comment: That would be great if BT can be disabled in BIOS.  Unfortunately, not possible.  However, I have found a way to uninstall the Bluetooth drivers and to block the BT driver updates (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/take-back-control-driver-updates-windows-10/).  But even after performing those steps, the laptop was still freezing.  The only solution was to update the Mediatek drivers - as described below.

Answer (score 1):

Problem finally solved manually!

Cause: Windows 10 and HP site are giving the WRONG (old) version of Mediatek (Ralink) drivers for this HP Envy laptop (15-j101ex).  Had to manually search for updated drivers on ALL the HP sites.  And after many wasted hours (trying to locate the drivers and turning OFF bluetooth permanently because someone suggested it) found the updated Mediatek drivers on a different HP site.  Please see the links below.

Solution:
Download the drivers for Mediatek Wireless LAN RT3290 adaptor:
http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=ob_150624_1#tab3

Download the drivers for Mediatek Bluetooth Adaptor RT3290:
http://h20566.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=vc_159313_1#tab3

Install the drivers and then turn ON "Virtualization Technology" in the BIOS and you should be good to go!!

HP Support could have been more HELPFUL:
The web site for this laptop should provide access to the latest drivers for Windows 10.  And the Windows database of drivers should be updated so that Windows 10 provides the LATEST drivers for HP laptops.